# <table-valued function> is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'fnParseName' is not a recognized built-in function name.

On this query:

```
SELECT  fnParseName(DOCTORFIRSTNAME+' ' +DOCTORLASTNAME) 
  FROM [PracticeandPhysician]
```

Here's the code for fnParseName

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseName]
               (@FullName NVARCHAR(128))
RETURNS @FullNameParts TABLE  (FirstName  NVARCHAR(128),
                               Middle     NVARCHAR(128),
                               LastName   NVARCHAR(128))
AS
  BEGIN
    ... function body that populates @FullNameParts ...
    RETURN
  END
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: it's a table valued function if that helps

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a table-valued function. So you probably meant:

```
SELECT p.DOCTORFISTNAME, p.DOCTORLASTNAME, t.FirstName, t.Middle, t.LastName
  FROM dbo.[PracticeandPhysician] AS p
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnParseName(p.DOCTORFIRSTNAME + ' ' + p.DOCTORLASTNAME);
```

Note that you can't say:

```
SELECT dbo.TableValueFunction('foo');
```

Any more than you could say:

```
SELECT dbo.Table;
--or
SELECT dbo.View;
```

You can, however, say:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnParseName('foo bar');
--or
SELECT FirstName, Middle, LastName FROM dbo.fnParseName('foo bar');
```

(Not that I have validated that your function does what you think, or does so efficiently.)

Please [always use the `dbo.` prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) as others have suggested.

Comment: Didn't I show that in the very first sample, using `CROSS APPLY`? It should output columns from every input row in `dbo.[PracticeandPhysician]`.

Comment: "CROSS APPLY returns only rows from the outer table that produce a result set from the table-valued function." From the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx

Comment: plus one for 'always use the dbo prefix'

Answer (score 12):

You always have to prefix SQL function calls with the schema name `dbo.` or the schema name for that function (dbo is the default schema).

```
SELECT dbo.fnParseName(--etc
```

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnParseName", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: @MattGibson nope definitely not, i can send u snapshot if u want

Comment: @MattGibson it's a table valued function if that helps

Comment: Yes check you didn't accidentally create the function on master.. its easily done when opening a new connection to run a sql batch.

Comment: If you run "sp_help 'fnParseName'" what does it return?

Comment: @PeterWishart yes i agree with you but i confirmed that i created it on the correct db

Comment: @Peter it's a table-valued function. The prefix is important but the real problem is you can't reference a table-valued function like an expression (though you can with a scalar UDF).

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that, @Aaron. Couldn't quite see what would be returned, given the syntax, even if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

UDFs/Functions need to be prefixed with the schema name (most likely "dbo").  Change the call to

```
SELECT
    dbo.fnParseName(DOCTORFIRSTNAME + ' ' + DOCTORLASTNAME) 
FROM
    [PracticeandPhysician]
```

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnParseName", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: The schema prefix is not the issue here (while it will still be required, there is a more fundamental syntax issue).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is similar to what I encountered too. Scalar function and Table inline functions are quite different in terms of implementation. See below for the diiferent

```
 Create function udfCountry
 (
@CountryName varchar(50)
 )
 returns varchar(2)
 as 
 BEGIN
 Declare @CountryID varchar(2),
    @Result varchar(2)

 Select @CountryID = Country from 
dbo.GeoIPCountryNames where CountryName = @CountryName

set @Result = isNull(@CountryID, 'NA')
if @Result = 'NA'
set @Result = 'SD'
return @Result
End
```

//Implementation

```
select dbo.[udfCountry]('Nigeria')
```

// sample result

```
NG
```

// Inline table function sample

```
 Create FUNCTION  ConditionEvaluation
 (
  @CountrySearch varchar(50)
 )
 returns @CountryTable table 
(
Country varchar(2),
CountryName varchar(50)
 )
 as 

 Begin

 Insert into @CountryTable(Country, CountryName)
 Select Country, CountryName from GeoIPCountryNames
 where Country like '%'+@CountrySearch+'%'
 return 
 end
```

//Implementation sample

```
 Declare @CountrySearch varchar(50)
 set @CountrySearch='a'
 select * from  ConditionEvaluation(@CountrySearch)
```

the parttern of implementating scalar is quite different inline table. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the value returned by tfn in a variable of stored procedure, you can do it this way:

```
select  @my_local_variable_in_procedure = column_name_returned_from_tfn from dbo.my_inline_tfn (@tfn_parameter)
```