# SQL Server: Cannot execute existing scalar function from within table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2017

I created this scalar function, without any problems.
But I can't execute it from another function (inline table-valued).

```
USE [test]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[NameFromEnumerationID]    Script Date: 10/9/2018 6:46:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NameFromEnumerationID]
(
    @EnumerationIDParam INT NOT NULL
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR ( 48 )
WITH    NATIVE_COMPILATION ,
        SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH (  TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT      ,
                        LANGUAGE                    = N'English'    )
    RETURN CHOOSE ( @EnumerationIDParam                         ,
                    CAST ( N'ExampleName1' AS NVARCHAR ( 48 ) ) ,
                    CAST ( N'ExampleName2' AS NVARCHAR ( 48 ) ) ,
                    CAST ( N'ExampleName3' AS NVARCHAR ( 48 ) ) ,
                    CAST ( N'ExampleName4' AS NVARCHAR ( 48 ) ) ,
                    CAST ( N'ExampleName5' AS NVARCHAR ( 48 ) ) ,
                    CAST ( N'ExampleName6' AS NVARCHAR ( 48 ) ) ) ;
END
GO
```

When I try to create another function that executes the above function, I receive the error:
`'NameFromEnumerationID' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NamesFromEnumerationIDs]
(
    @EnumerationIDListParam [IntList] NOT NULL READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT  [Value]                                 AS [ID]                     ,
/* ERROR */ NameFromEnumerationID   ( [Value] )     AS [EnumerationName]        ,
    UPPER ( [NameFromEnumerationID] ( [Value] ) )   AS [EnumerationNameUpper]   ,
            [IsEnumerationIDValid]  ( [Value] )     AS [IsValid]
        FROM @EnumerationIDListParam
)
GO
```

For the parameter to the second function, the `IntList` type is very simple:

```
USE [test]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[IntList]    Script Date: 10/9/2018 6:55:56 AM ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntList] AS TABLE(
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

How do I execute the first function as part of the query in the second function?

Comment: Add the schema name: dbo.NameFromEnumerationID( [Value] )

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I could have sworn I had tried that ... it seems to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<table-valued function> is not a recognized built-in function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575622/table-valued-function-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is not a recognized built-in function name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41218952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the schema name: `dbo.NameFromEnumerationID( [Value] )`

[dba.stackexchange.com: Why is the schema prefix (dbo) mandatory when we call a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142984/why-is-the-schema-prefix-dbo-mandatory-when-we-call-a-function)